# Image rotate and scale

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to rotate and scale a `UIImageView` image with the help of `UISlider`.

There are three condition when `UISlider` value is in its middle position then the original image will be its original position.
Second case, When slider value is maximum then image will rotate with 45 degree add bit scale.
Third case, when slider value is in its minimum position then image will rotate 45 degree in opposite direction and also bit scale.
I used this code but did not get desired result.

```
-(IBAction)sliderMoved:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"landscape.jpg"]; 
    photoImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(slider.value * 2*M_PI_2 / slider.maximumValue);
    CGFloat scale=0.5;
    NSLog(@"sliderVlaue=%f",slider.value);
    if ((slider.value) >(0.75)) {
        scale =(.25+ slider.value);
    } else {
        scale =(0.75 +slider.value);
    }
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = photoImage.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
    [photoImage setTransform:newTransform];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried my self with the help of given hints and able to way out from my problem. here is the code`

```
in you h file declare  UIImageView *photoImage;
UIView *canvas;

CAShapeLayer *_marque;
```

And in view did load

```
if (!_marque) {
    _marque = [CAShapeLayer layer] ;
    _marque.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _marque.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    _marque.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    _marque.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
    _marque.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
    _marque.bounds = CGRectMake(photoImage.frame.origin.x, photoImage.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
    _marque.position = CGPointMake(photoImage.frame.origin.x + canvas.frame.origin.x, photoImage.frame.origin.y + canvas.frame.origin.y);
}
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:_marque];

    - (IBAction) sliderMoved:(id)sender
     {

    CGFloat scale=0;
   NSLog(@"sliderVlaue=%f",slider.value);
   if ((slider.value) >(0.77)) {
    scale =(.5+ slider.value);
    photoImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(((4*slider.value)*(M_PI/180)));
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = photoImage.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale-.25, scale-.25);

    [photoImage setTransform:newTransform];

    NSLog(@"max=%f",scale);


}else if(slider.value< 0.77 && slider.value >.73){
   photoImage.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    photoImage.frame=imageframe;
     scale =(0.5 +slider.value);
    NSLog(@"mid=%f",scale);
}
else{
    scale =(.77 +(1.0-slider.value));
    photoImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((((-4)*(slider.value))*(M_PI/180)));
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = photoImage.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

    [photoImage setTransform:newTransform];
     NSLog(@"min=%f",scale);

}


    //_lastScale = 1;
[self showOverlayWithFrame:photoImage.frame];
}

-(void)showOverlayWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

if (![_marque actionForKey:@"linePhase"]) {
    CABasicAnimation *dashAnimation;
    dashAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"lineDashPhase"];
    [dashAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
    [dashAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0f]];
    [dashAnimation setDuration:0.5f];
    [dashAnimation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
    [_marque addAnimation:dashAnimation forKey:@"linePhase"];
}

_marque.bounds = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
_marque.position = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + canvas.frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + canvas.frame.origin.y);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, frame);
[_marque setPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);
 _marque.hidden = NO;    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
CGFloat Angle=(((int)slider.value*M_PI)/180);
transform=CGAffineTransformScale(transform, photoImage.scale, photoImage.scale);
transform= CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,Angle);
photoImage.transform = transform;
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, but there is an error in your code at point photoImage.scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for image rotation

```
imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

For scaling an image

```
-(IBAction)grow
{   
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    CGRect b = grower.bounds;
    b.size.height = 200;
    b.size.width = 200;
    grower.bounds =  b;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: i just want to rotate 45 and only on time when slider value is max

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imgToRotate = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48, 208, 240, 240)];
    imgToRotate.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rtm.jpeg"];
    [self.view addSubview:imgToRotate];  
}


- (IBAction)slideToRotateScale:(UISlider *)sender
{
    sender.maximumValue = 1.0;
    sender.minimumValue = -1.0;
    imgToRotate.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(fabsf(sender.value), fabs(sender.value)), sender.value*M_PI/4);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it rotate 45 degree in only one direction and also no scalng

Comment: I am sorry as I have set the maximum value = 1.0 and minimum value = -1.0 in the Attribute Inspector itself. add the Above two lines to set max and min values. It will work.